# Using appUser scoped tokens in Smooch

Tags: javascript, jwt, smooch

I am developing a widget that users in my company can use to communicate with end-users through Smooch.

The widget is accessible through the web browser and the communication goes mostly through a layer developed in node. However, I was trying to send attachments directly to Smooch to reduce the load in the server.

As I understand, it is necessary to use a token with a appUser scope to avoid issues with CORS.

I create the token using the following code

```
app.get('/getjwt', (req, res) => {
      var token = jwt.sign({ scope: 'appUser', userId: req.body.userId }, SECRET, { header: { 'alg': 'HS256', 'type': 'JWT', 'kid': '[app key ID]' } });
      res.send({ jwt: token });
});
```

I try to use the generated token (using Postman for tests) by making a request with Authorization Bearer [my generated token] and I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalid_auth",
        "description": "Invalid JWT header. Missing key id (kid)"
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the 'kid' value to the app ID, the API key ID, and the API key Secret and I'm always getting the same error. What am I missing? Am I supposed to pass the Key ID somewhere else?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me, what version of `jsonwebtoken` are you using? In v6.0.0 the `headers` option was renamed to `header`, so if you're using 5.x or lower your code should look like this instead

```
var token = jwt.sign({ scope: 'appUser', userId: req.body.userId }, SECRET, { headers: { 'alg': 'HS256', 'type': 'JWT', 'kid': '[app key ID]' } });
```

That said, Smooch already provides a fully functional web messenger / widget that you should use instead of attempting to build your own. It provides event hooks and methods to build a fully custom UI if that's what you're trying to achieve. See https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/smooch